# What do $l+p$ and $lp$, where $p$ is a point and $l$ is a line, mean in geometery?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, analytic-geometry, finite-fields, finite-geometry

I am looking at a graph theory problem that describes the partite sets of a bipartite as two copies of the $(m+1)$-dimensional vector space over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ ($p$ is prime and $n\geq 1$ is an integer), $P$ and $L$. They call the elements of $P$ "points" and the elements of $L$ "lines".

They say a point $(p)=(p_1, \ldots, p_{m+1})\in P$ is adjacent to a line $[l]=[l_1, \ldots, l_{m+1}]$ if and only if

$$ l_{i+1}+p_{i+1}=l_ip_1  $$

for every $i\in \left\{1,2,\ldots, m \right\}$.

I would like to know what the sum on the left hand side and the product on the right side mean geometrically in terms of lines and points. Perhaps I should ignore the geometric meaning? I just want to know how I should be viewing the above definition.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try this out on some simple example, like the [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane)?

Comment: Is the index of $p$ in the rhs of the equation supposed to be $1$ or is it $i$?

Comment: @A.P. It is a $1$. I will try your example.

Comment: Could you tell us where this problem comes from, more precisely?

Comment: First, do you know what a [projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space) is? That's basically what's going on here: you can think of a *point* in $\Bbb{P}^m(\Bbb{F}_{p^n})$ as a tuple $(p_1,\dotsc,p_{m+1}) \in \Bbb{F}_{p^n}^{m+1} \setminus \{0\}$. Here a *line* is the set of solutions to an equation of the form $l_1 p_1 + \dotsc + l_{m+1} p_{m+1} = 0$ with $l_i \in \Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ not all zero. Interestingly, you can observe that multiplying that equation by a non-zero constant gives the same line, thus you can think of a line as...

Comment: a point in (another copy of) $\Bbb{P}^m(\Bbb{F}_{p^n})$! Now, the lhs and rhs of those equations have no meaning by themselves, but they are used to define a relationship between some points and some lines. The problem (which is why I'm not posting this as an answer) is that I can't figure out what that relationship (which AFAIK isn't standard) is supposed to mean geometrically. In the Fano plane, for example, there are $7$ points and each point is contained in $3$ out of $7$ lines. It turns out that, say, the point $(0,0,1)$ is adjacent to the lines $[1,0,1]$ and $[0,0,1]$...

Comment: but without further information I can't figure out why someone would want to single out precisely those lines.

Answer (score -1):

There is little geometric meaning in the addition and multiplication - because the formula is used to *define* the very incidence structure of points and lines of this example structure.

Instead, in order to justify the denotion as "points" and "lines", you should verify that the arithmetic properties of $+$ and $\times$  can be used to *show* that this incidence structure satisfies the axioms of geometry. 
For example, if $p,q$ are distinct points, then we want to show that there exist one and only one $l$ such that both points are incident with that line, i.e., the system of equations  $$\begin{align}p_{i+1}+x_{i+1}&=p_1x_i,\\q_{i+1}+x_{i+1}&=q_1x_i\end{align}$$ has exactly once solution.